# Implement "related items" feature using SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I need to implement a "related items" feature, i.e. to allow items from the same table to be arbitrarily linked to each other in a many-to-many fashion. Something similar to how news websites show related articles.

Also, I need the relationship to be bi-directional, something like this:

```
a = Item()
b = Item()
a.related.append(b)
assert a in b.related # True
```

Now, on SQL level I imagine this could be solved by modifying the "standard" many-to-many relationship so 2 records are inserted into the association table each time an association is made, so (a -> b) and (b -> a) are two separate records.

Alternatively, the join condition for the many-to-many table could somehow check both sides of the association, so roughly instead of `... JOIN assoc ON a.id = assoc.left_id ...` SQLAlchemy would produce something like `... JOIN assoc ON a.id = assoc.left_id OR a.id = assoc.right_id ...`

Is there a way to configure this with SQLAlchemy so the relation works similar to a "normal" many-to-many relationship?

It's likely that I'm just don't know the correct terminology - everything I came up with - "self-referential", "bidirectional", "association" - is used to describe something else in SQLAlchemy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [Attribute Events](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/events.html#attribute-events) should do the job. See the sample code below, where little ugly piece of code is solely for the purpose of avoid endless recursion:

```
class Item(Base):
    __tablename__ =  "item"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(255), nullable=False)

    # relationships
    related = relationship('Item', 
            secondary = t_links,
            primaryjoin = (id == t_links.c.from_id),
            secondaryjoin = (id == t_links.c.to_id),
    )

_OTHER_SIDE = set()
from sqlalchemy import event
def Item_related_append_listener(target, value, initiator):
    global _OTHER_SIDE
    if not((target, value) in _OTHER_SIDE):
        _OTHER_SIDE.add((value, target))
        if not target in value.related:
            value.related.append(target)
    else:
        _OTHER_SIDE.remove((target, value))

event.listen(Item.related, 'append', Item_related_append_listener)

# ...
a = Item()
b = Item()
a.related.append(b)
assert a in b.related # True
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for mentioning Attribute Events. However, I don't quite understand the role of _OTHER_SIDE and use of `global`. To prevent recursion, wouldn't something like the following suffice: `if target not in value.related and value != target:\n value.related.append(target)`. I'll try to implement it and will report back.

Comment: Ahh, ok, I see - the listener is called *before* the value is appended to the collection, so when we modify the other side's related collaction from the listener, the remote side's listener is also invoked before the remote item is added to the collection. So I used a similar approach, although to avoid using a global variable I set a transient attribute on the `target` object to prevent recursion.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness sake, here's the code I ended up with; the listener method is slightly different to avoid using a global variable, an also there's a listener for `remove` event.

```
import sqlalchemy as sa

related_items = sa.Table(
    "related_items",
    Base.metadata,
    sa.Column("id", sa.Integer, primary_key=True),
    sa.Column("from_id", sa.ForeignKey("items.id")),
    sa.Column("to_id", sa.ForeignKey("items.id")),
)


class Item(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'items'
    ...
    related = sa.orm.relationship('Item',
            secondary = related_items,
            primaryjoin = (id == related_items.c.from_id),
            secondaryjoin = (id == related_items.c.to_id),
        )


def item_related_append_listener(target, value, initiator):

    if not hasattr(target, "__related_to__"):
        target.__related_to__ = set()

    target.__related_to__.add(value)

    if target not in getattr(value, "__related_to__", set()):
        value.related.append(target)

sa.event.listen(Item.related, 'append', item_related_append_listener)


def item_related_remove_listener(target, value, initiator):
    if target in value.related:
        value.related.remove(target)

sa.event.listen(Item.related, 'remove', item_related_remove_listener)
```

Comment: Great, thanks for sharing. it is cleaner to use an attribute. Looking at you code, I think if you do following steps `a.related.append(b); a.related.remove(b); a.related.append(b);` the `asssert a in b.related` will fail, because you do not clean the `__related_to__` set on remove, so the other side will not be added second time.